# TRIM on SQL Server 2017, but Compat Level 130 works?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to determine why this works.  I would expect that it would fail with an error if the server is not 2017 (in this case it is) and the compat level of the DB is not 140 (it is currently 130 and is successful).

```
SELECT TRIM('FOO')
```

This also works for translate.

Is there any reason this is working or am I misinterpreting something?  Are there any other functions to be aware of that may work with this behavior?

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) say 2017 and later, there is no indication of a compatibility level requirement

Answer (score 0):

In further testing, it seems the compatibility level does not influence the availability of the 2017+ functions like TRIM and TRANSLATE.  It seems more likely that they are version of SQL dependent and thus available in only 2017+.

Comment: Read the documentation for compatibility level - it does not guarantee that code works (or fails) when run in different **versions** of sql server. TRIM is rather recent - 2017 sounds correct but not certain.